# How To Reference Dynamic JQuery HTML Tags

Tags: jquery, html

There's a lot of similar questions out there but they're all about how to write the dynamically created ID tags, not now to reference them when attempting to utilize the IDs. Below, I'm posting the first function that creates the table with an ID tag based on the SessionId in the `<tr>` tag (see the code comment that says "This is the important part".

Below that I have the function for what I want it to do. I am attempting to change what's in the table row after the button within that row is clicked.

I have this code that creates the tags:

```
$('#lookup').click(function (event) {
        $('#results').html("");
        $('#btn').html("");
        $('#reset').html("");
        strUser = $('#userid').val();
        lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "username":"' + strUser + '" }');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/FindUser",
            data: lookfor,
        }).done(function (data) {
            var html = "";
            var err = "";
            var count = 0;
            var elite = false;

            $.each(data, function (entryIndex, entry) {

                if (entryIndex == 0) {
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<th>Username</th>";
                    html += "<th>Server</th>";
                    html += "<th>App</th>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                }
                if (entry.Result) {
                    err = "<tr>";
                    err += "<td>" + entry.Result + "</td>";
                    err += "</tr>";
                } else {  //**This is the important part here**:
                    html += "<tr id=Session" + entry.SessionId + ">";
                    html += "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessid\" value=\"" + entry.SessionId + "\" id=\"SessionId\">" + entry.UserId + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessid\" value=\"" + entry.ServerName + "\" id=\"ServerName\">" + entry.ServerName + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sessid\" value=\"" + entry.AppName + "\" id=\"AppName\">" + entry.AppName + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><a href=\"/Home/Details?SessionId=" + entry.SessionId + "&ServerName=" + entry.ServerName + "\">Details</a></td>";
                    html += "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Log Off\" runat=\"server\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"logoffsession\" /></td>";
                    html += "</tr>";
                }
                if (entry.Elite) {
                    elite = true;
                }
                count++;
            });
            if (err.length > 0) {
                $('#results').append($(err));
            } else {
                $('#results').append($(html));
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                var btn = "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Log Off All Sessions\" runat=\"server\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"logoff\" /></td>";
                $('#reset').append($(btn));
            } else if (elite) {
                var btn = "<td width=\"50\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Reset Elite Profile\" runat=\"server\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"resetelite\" /></td>";
                $('#reset').append($(btn));
            } else {

            }
        });
    });
```

Now here's what I want to do with it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#logoffsession", function (event) {
            var SessionId = $('#SessionId').val();
            var ServerName = $('#ServerName').val();
            var AppName = $('#AppName').val();
            var Pattern = /Elite/;
            var exists = Pattern.test(AppName);
            lookfor = JSON.parse('{ "sessionid":"' + SessionId + '","servername":"' + ServerName + '" }');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/LogOffSession",
                data: lookfor,
            }).done(function (data) {
                var html = "<td>" + data.Result + "</td>"

                //**Right here below is what I want to do**:
                $("'#Session" + SessionId + "'").html("");
                $("'#Session" + SessionId + "'").append($(html));
            });
        });
    });
```

Calling it by `$("'#Session" + SessionId + "'")` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: `$("#Session" + SessionId).html("");`. Way too  many quotes

Comment: That did the trick, I thought I had to have single quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: I also spotted another error, which I have no idea how it works this way:
`html += "<tr id=Session" + entry.SessionId + ">"` -> `html += "<tr id=\"Session" + entry.SessionId + "\">";`

Comment: Thanks, that may have worked as a fluke.  I'm realizing when I click the button on the row it's not picking the right row's SessionId, it's picking the row above it. It needs to know which "Log Off" button I'm clicking. How do I reference the right one on this line? `var SessionId = $('#SessionId').val();`

Comment: Nevermind I think I figured that out with a parent/child solution.

Comment: Weirdly the earlier solution stopped working when I implemented this one, I don't think anything changed as far as this solution goes. Strange.